# full duplex communication over the web w/o flash sockets

Tags: javascript, ajax, comet, websocket

A web application I'm helping to develop is faced with a well-known problem: we want to be able to let users know of various events and so forth that can occur at any time, essentially at random, and update their view accordingly. Essentially, we need to allow the server to push requests to individual clients, as opposed to the client asking the server.

I understand that WebSockets are an effort to address the problem; however, after a bit of looking around into them, I understand that a) very few web browsers currently offer native websocket support; b) to get around this, you either use flash sockets or some sort of AJAX long-polling; c) a special websockets server must be used.

Now, we want to offer our service without Flash. And any sort of servers must have some sort of load-balancing capabilities, or at least some software that *can* do load balancing for them.

As of 2008, everyone was saying that Comet-based solutions (e.g., Bayeux) were the way to go for these sort of situations. However, the various protocols seem to have not had much work put into them since then—which leads (finally) to the question.

Is Bayeux-flavored Comet still the right tool for jobs like this? If not, what is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to Comet/Bayeux that has proven to be working is the combination of an XMPP server such ejabberd or OpenFire and StropheJS developed by Jack Moffitt (his website is http://metajack.im/).  The limitation of XMPP is it can only transports text and not binary payload.

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets sounds like the ideal solution to your problem - I would not recommend going the comet/bayeux path.
Regarding your first two concerns:

> a) very few web browsers currently offer native websocket support

WebSocket servers tend to offer emulation techniques for browser that don't have native WebSocket support. [Here you can read about the emulation](http://blog.kaazing.com/2011/11/17/the-industrys-best-websocket-emulation-real-time-web-apps-for-all-your-customers-even-if-theyre-on-ie6/) that one of the vendors, Kaazing offers [disclaimer: I work for [Kaazing]](http://kaazing.com).

> b) [WebSocket emulation uses] flash sockets or some sort of AJAX
>   long-polling

Not quite the case. Doing emulation well is not simple, but it can be done. Long polling is pretty much the last resort. The Kaazing Gateway, for example, always uses better emulation than long polling.

Kaazing also offers an XMPP edition of the WebSocket Gateway, allowing you to build an HTML5 app using XMPP from your JavaScript environment directly. The underlying transport layer of XMPP is WebSockets (native or emulated).